# RxJS/Observable: How to set ordering for pipe methods

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a method `run` in class `Some` that return Observable and has `pipe` inside of this method. And I have one more `pipe` when execute method `run`.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, tap, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

class Some {
  run() {
    return of('Some request').pipe(
      tap((res) => {
        console.log('First -> ', res);
      })
    );
  }
}

new Some().run().pipe(
  map(res => console.log(`Second -> ${res}`))
).subscribe();
```

And the console will print

`First -> Some request`

`Second -> Some request`

**The my question is:** I need do some operations inside of method after this `pipe` -> `new Some().run().pipe()` will be completed. If based on this example I want to see in console

first:

`Second -> Some request`

and after

`First -> Some request`

Comment: I don't think that's possible without moving the tap() elsewhere: if you need to print the emitted value, it has to be emitted first. And before being emitted, the tap() operator is always invoked.

Comment: `tap`  is not required for me, I need to do some operations with `Observable` inside of method and outside in order what I described.

Comment: If you want "delay" the tap to a next time I think you can enclose the response in a setTimeout: 'tap(res=>{setTimeout(()=>console.log(res))}`

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the mapping function to the `run` method:

```js
  run(mappingFunction: (Observable<any>) => Observable<any>) {
    return of('Some request').pipe(
      map(res => mappingFunction(res)),
      tap(console.log)
    );
  }
```

Of course you can apply this concept to any function you'd want to pass to any RxJS operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can feed an operator function as an argument to run:

```
run(operator) {
  return of('Some request').pipe(
    operator,
    tap((res) => {
      console.log('First -> ', res);
    })
  );
}

run(input$ => input$.pipe(tap(v => console.log(v, “second”))).subscribe()
```

Comment: Simply passing the operator function to `run` would work just as well: `run(tap(v => console.log(v, “second”)))`. Also consider typing the parameter to restrict what `run` accepts e.g. `run<R>(operator: OperatorFunction<string, R>)` or with `MonoTypeOperatorFunction<string>`.

Comment: But then you can’t have multiple steps in a passed operator,

Comment: When your typing `run` you mean? You're still able to pass a function in. Have you tried it?

Comment: No I definitely should type it, I just didn’t cause lazy, but I was trying to demo a method that would allow the passing of n operators